# Inno Setup: Why RequireRadioSelection is unknown on a TInputOptionWizardPage?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

Inno Setup documentation says that [`TInputOptionWizardPage`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses&anchor=TInputOptionWizardPage) have a  `CheckListBox` property.

`CheckListBox` is of type [`TNewCheckListBox`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptclasses.htm#TNewCheckListBox) which has a property `RequireRadioSelection`

Thus, I was expecting this code to build:

```pascal
procedure InitializeWizard;
var
    Page: TInputOptionWizardPage;
begin
    Page := CreateInputOptionPage(wpWelcome, '', '', '', True, False);
    Page.Add('Option 1');
    Page.Add('Option 2');
    Page.CheckListBox.RequireRadioSelection := True;
end;
```

It does not, compiler says that RequireRadioSelection is an Unknown identifier.

All other properties I've tried like `Page.WantTabs := True;` are compiling.

Did I misunderstood something or could that be a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contrary to the documentation, the property was not exposed to Pascal Script.

This has been fixed in Inno Setup 5.6:
https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/commit/1152ce6d163bbc0f8292d75b681668e3343d01a9